# How do you divide each number in an array by a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need a simple way to divide all the numbers (contained in objects) in an array by a variable in javascript (no jquery or other libraries) :

```
var divisor = 16;
var array = [{"x":0,"y":16},{"x":16,"y":32},{"x":32,"y":48}];
```

Expected Result:

```
[{"x":0,"y":1},{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":2,"y":3}];
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why are you adding strings within each element? Also, look into `for` loops.

Comment: Are those objects always of the structure `{x: 1, z: 2}`?

Comment: Jeezus, so many people eager to make someone's homework. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
var divisor = 16;
var array = [{"x":0,"y":16},{"x":16,"y":32},{"x":32,"y":48}];

for(var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++){
    array[i] = {'x':array[i].x/divisor,'y':array[i].y/divisor};
}
```

In case you are likely to extend the objects in the future, you might want to do it like this, instead:

```
for(var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++){
    array[i].x /= divisor;  // `a[i].x /= d` is shorthand for `a[i].x = a[i].x / d`
    array[i].y /= divisor;
}
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't overwrite `array[i]`, saving possible other properties.

Comment: This can be a problem in the future if the dictionaries gain more keys, like *speed* or something. Suddendly they get removed with your code.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly: that's out of the scope of the question, imo, but I've edited in another option. If the downvote's yours, could you consider removing it?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a callback:

```
var divisor = 16;
var array = [{"x":0,"y":16},{"x":16,"y":32},{"x":32,"y":48}];

array = array.map(function(v){
  return {x: v.x / divisor, y: v.y / divisor};
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [Array.prototype.map() is IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: You should either use the `forEach` method or don't modify `v`. It works in this example but `map` is not supposed to modify the original objects.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Also available in all other modern browsers and easy to shim for the older ones.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Easy to shim, yes, but I think it's something that should be mentioned when using relatively new features.

Comment: Well, if this is indeed homework, I think his teacher expects him to use `for` :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony: But a teacher would be impressed with a student who could use **and explain** `map` instead!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i]["x"] /= divisor;
    array[i]["y"] /= divisor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Deep divide here.

```
var divideBy = function(object, divider) {
    if (typeof(object) == 'number') return object/divider;
    for (var i in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            object[i] = divideBy(object[i], divider);
        }
    }
    return object;
}

var obj = [{a: 16, b: 32}, {c: 0, d: 48, e: 160}];
console.log(divideBy(obj, 16));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is as a function so you can re-use it. It is not limited to just 2 variables per object.

```
function divideArray(array, divisor) {
    var i = array.length, a, k;
    while (i) { // loop over each item in array
        a = array[--i];
        for (k in a) { // loop over each key in object
            if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)) { // ignore inherited keys
                a[k] = a[k] / divisor; // calculate
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

// use with your example
var divisor = 16;
var array = [{"x":0,"y":16},{"x":16,"y":32},{"x":32,"y":48}];
array = divideArray(array, divisor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        var divisor = 16;
        var array = [{"x":0,"y":16},{"x":16,"y":32},{"x":32,"y":48}];
        var i=0;
        for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            array[i]["y"]=array[i]["y"]/divisor;
            array[i]["x"]=array[i]["x"]/divisor;
        }
```

Comment: You forgot about `array[i]["x"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var divisor = 16;
    var array = [{"x":0,"y":16},{"x":16,"y":32},{"x":32,"y":48}];
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        array[i]["y"]=array[i]["y"]/divisor;
        array[i]["x"]=array[i]["x"]/divisor;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] and elaborate your answer as to why OP or other people can try this?